# Improve accuracy of Tesseract

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I am using tess-two (Android port of Tesseract OCR engine). I am OCR'ing bills  and receipts. I am using OpenCV 3.0 to preprocess the image. I have successfully made a bill into a binary image along with adaptive thresholding.

Original image:

[image: Original]

Binary threshold of original:

[image: Binary]

Tesseract output.

```
PH:26051246/26145398
TIN=276302417620
CQSH/BILL
NO 009762 0 m 0 09-07-2015
DESCRIPTION on mm mu
_.__________
m 3.990 75.18 zoo-00
_____\
CASH 300-00
m: YOU----UISIT 9691!!
w TIN:276302417620
-\ c1 09:27:58 we no. 0
```

At present I have trained 3 dot-matrix fonts and two Merchant copy fonts. I have turned off the dictionary and added user-words for all five fonts. They are commonly used terms in Bills and Receipts. Strangely these changes don't seem to make any difference in the output. 
I resized the image so that the font size  is at least 12 pt. How do I improve the accuracy further? Can anyone specify a font or should I retrain the fonts.

Comment: If accuracy could be so easily improved don't you think that Tesseract's developers would have done that already? Why do you think that accuracy CAN be better than that? What I mean is, do you have proof that any OCR - ABBYY can produce higher quality recognition? If ABBYY can do better, then at least you know it can be theoretically done.

Comment: Good Point...I have other bills  which give upto 80% accuracy with slightly different parameters. On the other hand I have others not so accurate. So I know that the accuracy can be improved. Just expecting a new line of thought maybe...

Comment: Have you tried with ABBYY? They are the best OCR (but not free like Tesseract), so what it gives as results you can consider the best you can possibly get. If ABBYY gives you bad results on this image, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Unfortunately the project specifies only open source OCR engine...hence Tesseract. But will try ABBY once for test purpose.

Comment: I didn't say include ABBYY in your project, I said test with ABBYY. You install ABBYY on your machine, run that image and see the results. Anyway, that's as far as I can help, I personally don't think you can improve the recognition results - if they could be improved the developers would have already done so.

Comment: Superb recognition by ABBYY. 85% accuracy without training a font. I hope Tesseract will do a better job after I am through.